# Passing data to the instantiated View Controller

Tags: swift, swift3, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

Let's say we have a view controller which is the embedded in to the `UINavigationController`. We want to present it after successfully instantiated. For example:

```
if let navigationController = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiatedViewController(withIdentifier: "UINavigationController") as? UINavigationController {

 self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Well it's works, but we have a problem here. Because we want to pass a data to the view controller through the navigation controller. And what I have tried so far:

```
if let navigationController = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiatedViewController(withIdentifier: "UINavigationController") as? UINavigationController {

  let viewController = navigationController.topViewController as! CustomViewController
  viewController.stringValue = "Value" 

 self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)

  }
```

It is works perfectly. But I think it's not a best way. There's no another approaches or it's the right solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your current approach is good enough in it's own right.**
Still, if you want a better way of doing things I think you should look into the Coordinator pattern.

It's strange for the ViewController to bear the responsibility of initializing/configuring/presenting subsequent ViewControllers. Also, things get really tricky when you want to move a few things around i.e. change a few ViewControllers within a authentication flow for example. ViewControllers become dependent on other ViewControllers and the whole thing becomes a huge mess.

Using Coordinators is a not an easy feat as you might have to change the entire architecture of your app. I feel you should stick to the current implementation for now. However if you're up for it, here are a few resources to help you make the jump.

[Coordinators Redux (Theory behind Coordinators)](http://khanlou.com/2015/10/coordinators-redux/)

[An iOS Coordinator Pattern (pratical example)](https://will.townsend.io/2016/an-ios-coordinator-pattern)

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try using protocols. your code will be more readable and i think this is one of the best ways :)

Comment: What did you mean? What's the protocol?

Comment: try being specific, and give an answer. Provide an example of the protocol, showing the benefits versus the author's implementation